# Remove margin in Flutter PersistentFooterButtons

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to remove the default margin from `persistentFooterButtons`, but I can't find it because it receives a list of widgets.

I'm using `extendBody: true` in `Scaffold`.

**persistentFooterButtons margin**

[image: persistentFooterButtons margin]

```
    persistentFooterButtons: [
    Container(
      color: const Color.fromRGBO(240, 240, 240, 0.9),
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2, vertical: 2),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const Image(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/home.png'),
                      height: 35,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Início",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 10,
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
```

Comment: you can also try by wrapping it inside Stack and give this Container Position

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is coming from the source code of `scaffold.dart`. It is defined like this.

```dart
 child: Container(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8), //<-- this 
                child: OverflowBar(
                  spacing: 8,
                  overflowAlignment: OverflowBarAlignment.end,
                  children: widget.persistentFooterButtons!,
                ),
              ),
```

[Source-code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/6b92a00c373d000c5adf6a52f9e5ccc0cfa574ef/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart#L2971)

You can remove `padding` or set `0` or your local machine if it is ok to have this on your projects. You can switch between values based on your need. Also, you can also create a separate dart file for your project.

[image]

Another trick can be applied using `transform` but tap effect can be effected in this case.

```dart
Container(
  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, 8, 0),
   .....
```

Or I would say just use `bottomNavigationBar` on `Scaffold` instead of `persistentFooterButtons`

```dart
  bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          color: const Color.fromRGBO(240, 240, 240, 0.9),
          width: double.infinity,
          height:50, // the one prefered by your view
........
```

Comment: i changed it to bottomNavigationBar but it occupies the entire size do i have to put height in the container (https://ibb.co/Kjq8qJs)?

Comment: Yes I've tested with height:50